# Biztalk Ftp adapter issue

Tags: ftp, adapter, biztalk

I recently faced a problem with FTP adapter in BizTalk 2013.
I configured send adapter to send files to ftp server, files are picked up from folder (file transfer) and "passthroutransmit" to send port ftp adapter.

My problem is that file never end in send location (folder on ftp server) however I do not get any error in Biztalk.

I try to unenlist send port and then i get error `no subscriber`.
I ran out of options, I do not know where to look for error.
Have you guys any idea what it could be?

Comment: if you do a quick test and change the send port to be file system, do the files arrive there?  (I.e. It might not be an ftp issue).  So nothing gets suspended and there are no errors in the event viewer?

Comment: I have several  other port ( file system)  and it is work. just ftp make a problem for me. Yes no error show up.  i go to  event viewer and hub to look for any error and nothing show up.

Comment: strange - is there any chance they are arriving and being moved/deleted (I've been caught with this in the past)

Comment: i do not think about that. it is  any option i biztalk I can  set it up ?  it is strange for me too and since i do not have any error i  am not sure where to look for

Comment: I was more meaning if there might have been some file monitoring, or virus checking software that was deleting/moving the files - so they were actually getting there but you didn't have time to see them.  As I said in the first comment, if you're sure THIS send port is working (e.g. to file) then I'm stumped...sorry

Comment: First, try sending the file from the command line.  If it goes missing then, the issues is on the server.

Comment: Ok I fix a problem 

 NDJ -  good sugestion, it was as you say. I contact administrator and he check and confirm file was moved after  they was drop in that location. he just forgot  tell me about that.

Comment: i'll add it as an answer then, as it avoids future readers trawling through the comments - feel free to accept the answer if it has indeed solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as per comments/responses above)
If there are no errors reported and nothing is showing as suspended, it might well be that the files made it to their destination...and were perhaps moved/deleted by something on the target machine (e.g. an automated task or virus checking software).